# Regex matching end of list element

Tags: python, regex

My aim is to replace all word numbers within a list tag with corresponding number bullets. For example, with the following input:

```
<list>one goto school     two do play     three comeback      <!list>
```

I want the following output, but the matching should stop at the end of list:

```
<list>xx. goto school
|NEWLIN xx. do play
|NEWLIN xx. comeback
 <!list>
```

The [regular expression suggested in the answer](https://regex101.com/r/wDlNXZ/2) (also copied below) solves it but does not stop matching at the end of list.

```
((?<=\<list\>)|(?<=\|NEWLIN ))(one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine)
```

Comment: This doesn't look like Python code?

Comment: Your regex does not seem to match at all. Use a site like http://regex101.com to debug it until you find a fitting regex.

Comment: @RedX I have pasted from regex101 only

Comment: @RedX https://regex101.com/r/LUM6d5/1

Comment: What is `<list> ... <!list>`? Is that supposd to be XML? There are easier ways to get the contents of an XML element than using regex...

Comment: @stackit: Maybe https://ideone.com/n5jSAP will do?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew see updated question

Comment: Ok, but how do you know it is the `one` that is before `goto` should be replaced? What if there is `one` later? Or `two` before the `two` that is the bullet point? Like here: `<list>one two apples     two pears     three or two peaches      <!list>`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew NEWLIN is there

Comment: Something like https://ideone.com/PWEQjy?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest matching the blocks in between `<list>` and `<!list>` with `(?s)<list>.*?<!list>` and then replace what you need in those specific positions.

Here is a sample solution that can be further improved:

```
import re
s = "<list>one goto school\n|NEWLIN two do play\n|NEWLIN three comeback\n <!list>"
def repl(m):
    l = {'one':'1', 'two':'2', 'three':'3', 'four':'4', 'five':'5', 'six':'6', 'seven':'7', 'eight':'8', 'nine':'9'}
    k = r"|".join([key for key, value in l.iteritems()])
    return re.sub(r"(?:(?<=<list>)|(?<=\|NEWLIN ))(?:{})".format(k), lambda x: "{}.".format(l[x.group()]), m.group())

res = re.sub(r"(?s)<list>.*?<!list>", repl, s)
print(res)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/PWEQjy)

**Details**:

- The `(?s)<list>.*?<!list>` regex matches `<list>`, then any 0+ chars (as `(?s)` modifier lets `.` match any char incl. line break chars) and then `<!list>`
- In the `re.sub`, the callback `repl` method is passed, where the match object is processed
- Inside `repl` method, the dictionary with the necessary replacements is defined, the keys are used to create a regex with alternations and two lookbehinds (this can easily be changed into capturing groups, but the code will grow a tiny bit longer). Within the `re.sub`, the lambda is passed as the replacement, and it lets us use the match value to fetch the right dictionary value.